# Tags text appearing above tabs

Tags: bug, tags, design

The following started appearing today.

Was wondering if this was some sort of A/B testing.

[image]

Any tags entered into search appears just above the nav tabs.

Comment: Reproduced, I see this too, on a tag-search page with multiple tags. Annoying.

Comment: Same here, came to meta to ask this same thing.

Comment: Not sure if it's just me having never noticed before, but on the list of favourite tags, was it always titled "Public Q&A Favorite Tags"? That seems different... And what does "public" mean exactly?

Comment: @DavidG i don't think so, if you check meta (which isn't borked) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags+discussion but i'm not sure

Comment: @Tanner Yeah, that looks a lot more familiar. I'm guessing this is the first round of whatever is meant to replace the "new nav" or channels (or both!)

Comment: Add to that that this text is underlined and the _Newest_, _Featured_, _Votes_  tabs interrupt this underline. Truly horrible to see.

Comment: Yup just began today, was fine earlier today, then I refreshed, saw the 'thanks to some joe' banner, and then the spew of filtered tags covering the entire view. I have to scroll down now just to get to the first question :(

Comment: It should probably just resort to "..." instead of going over to multiple lines.

Comment: Dev here - we've got a fix going on this and should get resolved in the next day

Comment: @Martijn, are you sure that some possible internal considerations of public and "private channel" question differentiations are related to the public page layout? I wouldn't call this a duplicate.

Comment: @Victoria: this is absolutely a duplicate.

Comment: @Martijn, so all of us became after the fix members of "public, non channel" members, or what happened? I don't want to be a part of this test (to waste my time reporting something which is discarder in the end). If you want me to help, tell me ;-)

Comment: @Victoria: there is no A/B testing for the channels feature. Only a small number of people are part of a private alpha test and they are part of it because they agreed to be.

Comment: @Martijn, I haven't agreed to anything like that (as far as you hypnotized me by the Hypnotoad). So, well, it was a mistake of SE team? If so, ok, forgiven ;-) But I would expect to be straight to what's wrong. Or, what is an "alpha" user?

Comment: @Martijn, because I don't want to be any "alpha" user.. I'm not a rat, but a human who can help you reporting what's wrong but needs to know that (so I don't even accept any A/B tests without advice).

Comment: If you're not a rat who is that in the gif on your profile page? ¬_¬

Comment: @MartinSmith, it's a domesticated hamster, not a lab rat ;)