# What is a public question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I [searched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2B%2B%20or%20makefile) for questions tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) and on top of the page it is showing:

> **Public** questions tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile)

What is a public question? Aren't all questions public on Stack Overflow?

As pointed out in the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362156/what-is-a-public-question-on-stack-overflow#comment549657_362156) by @vaultah, this might be related to channels. Can anyone please confirm that?

Comment: Channels are coming: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352065/2301450

Comment: @vaultah I know about channels but honestly, I didn't read the full post. Are you sure that this is an intentional change due to channel?

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362222/whats-the-deal-with-public-qa-favorite-tags

Answer (score 49, accepted):

tl;dr This is a change we made for channels, but it shouldn't have squeaked out on to the production site for non-alpha users. We are working on a fix.

Details: When you are a member of a channel it is important for you to clearly understand your context. Are you looking at information available to anyone (public) or are you looking at information for your channel (private). There are a range of UX changes that we've put in place to address this issue. If you are not a member of a channel, then you shouldn't see any of these changes.

Comment: So this is the same issue as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362146/tags-text-appearing-above-tabs presumably.

Comment: Dev here - we've got a fix going on this and should get resolved in the next day

Comment: I wonder if @balpha is non-alpha or ... ? :)

Answer (score 14):

This (probably) shouldn't be shown to you as it doesn't appear that you're a member of a private channel during the very early alpha period; but it's possible that we just print that by default now so folks know that yeah, there can be a private version of those results, too.

Regardless, that's why it's there. If you were in a channel, you might also see channel results that aren't public, which would be pretty clearly differentiated.

I'm tagging this as a bug on the off-chance that the string shouldn't be printed (for now), but eventually, public content might need to be more clearly labeled in other areas, and we might do that regardless of channel membership for perf or other reasons.

Comment: Yes, I'm not member of any channel yet and that's why it was confusing. Thanks Tim for the explanation.