# What's the deal with "Public Q&A Favorite Tags"?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I noticed recently that the "Favorite Tags" section on the side of the questions pages of the site has had its header changed to "Public Q&A Favorite Tags". I'm not sure this is a good idea, and I'm wondering why it was changed.

Will we be able to see Private Q&A Favorite Tags soon? What if we don't ever join a Private Q&A site? Will it revert back to "Favorite Tags"? The current longer title indicates that there are other Favorite Tags of mine out there somewhere, which is not the case.

I should clarify I am not signed up for Channels testing or any kind of Private Q&A testing/previews, at least that I'm aware of.

Comment: Possibly related: [What is a public question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362156/what-is-a-public-question-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is the same issue. This is channels alpha testing spilling over on accident it would seem.